# support v7 action bar with ActionBarActivity

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

There is no problem with importing, but problems come with activity. When I change `extends` from`Activity` to `ActionBarActivity` I get a lot of problems...

Why with `extends ActionBarActivity` I have no more methods like `findViewById()` or `getFragmentManager()`, etc.. How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you using Android Studio, or Eclipse?

Comment: ActionBarActivity is an Activity, so it should have findViewById, unless your imports are wrong.

Comment: I'm using Android Studio

Comment: oh... smells like a problem...

Answer (score 1):

Add the following lines into your build.gradle.

```
dependencies {
    // other dependencies
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+"
}
```

Comment: Where is build.grade i cant find?

Answer (score 1):

Your build.gradle file should look similar to below:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
}
```